# Spark streaming + processing files in HDFS stage directory

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am having a daemon process which dumps data as files in HDFS. I need to create a RDD over the new files, de-duplicate them and store them back on HDFS. The file names should be maintained while dumping back on HDFS.

Any pointers to achieve this?

I am open to achieve it with or without spark streaming.

I tried creating a spark streaming process which processes data directly ( using java code on worker nodes) and pushes it into HDFS without creating a RDD. 
But, this approach fails for larger files (greater than 15GB).

I am looking into JavaSparkContext.fileStreaming now.

Any pointers would be a great help.

Thanks and Regards,

Abhay Dandekar